# Rails Parent Child Model View Best Practice

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a view that displays records from both a parent (group in my case) and it's children (lines in my case) and whilst it works, I'm feeling that I'm not doing it the correct Rails MVC way.

My models are:

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lines, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
end

class Line < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
end
```

My Groups controller Print method is:

```
def print
  @groups = current_user.groups.order('position ASC').all
end
```

My print view is:

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Description:</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @groups.each do |group| %>
      <tr>
        <td><h3><%= group.description %></h3></td>
      </tr>
      <% group.lines.each do |line| %>
        <tr>
          <td><%= line.description %></td>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

My print method returns all groups which is fine just like the index method. It generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups"  WHERE "groups"."user_id" = ?  ORDER BY position ASC  [["user_id", 1]]
```

Where I think I'm going wrong is that I've got this code in my print **view** above:

```
lines group.lines.each do |line|
```

Each time this runs for each group, it generates another query like this (for **each** group:

```
SELECT "lines".* FROM "lines"  WHERE "lines"."group_id" = ?  [["group_id", 667]
```

This seems inefficient as the the query is running lots of times. I also strikes me that my query should actually be running from my controller and not my view (i.e. the proper Rails / MVC way).

How could I make this better?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do what's called [eager loading](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) ( as opposed to lazy loading ), you need to instruct rails to query for all the children in advance, instead of fetching each child in the loop, this can be done easily using the `includes` method

```
def print
  @groups = current_user.groups.includes(:lines).order(position: :asc)
end
```

This way you will only get 2 queries ( one for groups and one for lines ) and no queries when rendering the views

Comment: Thanks. I certainly didn't know about that.

Do I need to change my view at all as it still seems to be doing the line queries?

Comment: I found my problem. I had added an order in the view (since posting) and that was causing the multiple queries. When I move the order to the controller (combined with your instructions) it works perfectly. Cheers